# /mnt permissions keep changing on EC2 instances

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions, amazon-ec2

I have a few Ubuntu instances on EC2 where I use the /mnt instance storage to keep logs and other fungible stuff. In order to store user logs the /mnt directory needs to have 777 permissions:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /mnt
```

But periodically (about daily) permissions revert back to 755, for no apparent reason. Is there any way to make /mnt have write permissions for all users -- and keep it that way? I already have a task that runs on startup with the above line, but apparently it does not work.

A periodic task would be a last resort; honestly, I would like to understand the problem and solve it correctly. I have searched here and on the intertubes, no luck so far -- it is not an easily googleable question anyway.

Perhaps some mount options would do the trick? My fstab:

```
/dev/xvdb       /mnt    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0       2
```

Comment: What filesystem is on the volume being mounted?  You should almost never have permissions set to 0777.  That strongly indicates you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you just create a sub-directory to /mnt that will have the permissions you need?

Comment: @Zoredache Possibly, in that case I would like to know how to do things right.

Comment: @ernie I suppose so, but I would need to recreate that directory on boot using a task. I am already setting permissions to 777 in a task and it is not working. I would like to know what is wrong so that I can be sure that any new scheme works without mucking around.

Comment: I'm not sure what's resetting the mount points permissions (I'd guess something with how ephemeral storage works on EC2), but I'd guess that it won't change permissions on subdirectories . . .

Comment: @ernie I suppose that it will have to do. If you send an answer I will accept it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm not sure what's causing the permissions to reset (I would guess it's a policy around the ephemeral storage on an EC2 instance), but I think a more secure way to handle this would be to create a directory on /mnt with the permissions you need.

My theory is that this directory would not have it's permissions changed by whatever maintenance Amazon is running, plus it's more secure.